Odoo 14 pdf layout problem when I print the invoice there is no styles
I have installed a odoo14 solution with docker.
all works fine, but when I print an invoice pdf, the content is printed but it is not like the layout configured in the configuration.
there is no styles in the pdf printed :

can anyone help me please ?
what is the problem and how i can fix it ?
when I want to install the wkhtmltopdf inside the container, I recieve this message :
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Note, selecting 'wkhtmltox' instead of 'wkhtmltopdf'
wkhtmltox is already the newest version (1:0.12.5-1.buster).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
I think that there is a problem in dependency.

You probably have to add the the systems parameter with key report.url and value http://127.0.0.1:8069.

where I can do it ?

In the technical menu "System Parameters"?

my container is running on port 10017, 10017:8069 .
I should write 127.0.0.1:10017 or 127.0.0.1:8069 ?

the internal port, so 8069 (except you're starting odoo [not the container!] with another port)

it doesn't work :/

it works now, just I add 'http://'

oh f*** i've missed that. will edit my answer
